# Using push() to copy one array into another

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's assume I have a function like this

```
function createMultiDimArray() {
    let results = [];
    let current = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        current.push(i);

        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            results.push(current);
            current = [];
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

When I execute it

```
let arr = createMultiDimArray();
```

arr will look like this

```
[[1,2][3,4][5,6][7,8][9,10]]
```

I have tested it in multiple browsers and it seems to work. So apparently push() is creating a copy of the array passed to it instead of just using the reference, because otherwise arr would look like this (as current === [] when the function ends)

```
[[],[],[],[],[]]
```

I have searched the internet but I haven't found anything about this behavior of push(). So my question is: Is it safe to use push() to copy one array into another?

Comment: No! You're getting it wrong. `current = []` creates a new array.

Comment: @liam as you are very close to the "privileged user" group where every dupe vote will directly close the question, you should read questions a bit more carefully ... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`push` does not copy the array (or whatever argument it's given).

Rather, the line

```
current = [];
```

creates a new array object and assigns it to the array reference `current`.  From your analysis, I guess you assumed it would empty the existing array object referred to by `current`, but that's not the case.

Comment: That makes sense. Looks like my assumption was wrong indeed.

Answer (score 0):

No, in the code you are pushing the values into result using `results.push(current);`, and after that you create a new `current` array using `current = [];`. So after every even number you'll get sets of numbers pushed into `results`.